# Highcharts Heatmap: Why is the Y axis not respecting limits?

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart: https://jsfiddle.net/fujigoko/3j9f8mw7/1/

In this chart I am trying to limit the axis to go from September 1st to October 31st:

```
                      xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        min: Date.UTC(2023, 8, 1),
                        max: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 31)
                      },
                      yAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        min: Date.UTC(2023, 8, 1),
                        max: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 31)
                      },
```

but the limits are not respected on the Y axis:
[image]

Is there a way to force it to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Highcharts API:

> **min: number, null**
>
> The minimum value of the axis. If null the min value is automatically
> calculated.
>
> If the startOnTick option is true (default), the min value might be
> rounded down.
>
> ...

You need to disable `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` options.

```
  yAxis: {
    ...,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f50su6r4/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick